# How many independent components does the spin-tensor have?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

In [Loomis 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01545v1), the equations of motion for a spinning particle with 4-momentum $P^{\alpha}$ and spin-tensor $S^{\alpha \beta}$ are considered.

It is stated in the paper that these equations of motion

> give the time evolution of the four components of momentum, $P^{\alpha}$, and the six components of spin, $S^{\alpha \beta}$

Clearly in a 4D spacetime, $P^{\alpha}$ does have 4 components. **My question is** why does $S^{\alpha \beta}$ only have six components? I can see that the symmetry $S^{\alpha \beta} = S^{\beta \alpha}$ will reduce the number of independent components to 10, but I cannot see how to reduce this further to 6?

Thanks

Comment: $S_{\alpha\beta}$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: Just write out the most general antisymmetric $4\times4$ matrix and count the number of independent components (I presume you already did this for a symmetric matrix since you reached the correct number 10 for that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spin tensor is actually antisymmetric. For example, it can be related (at least in flat spacetime) to the spin vector $S^\mu$ as

$$S_{\mu\nu} = \frac12 \epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}u^\alpha S^\beta.$$

If you doubt this, take a look at equation I.1a, where they contract the spin tensor with the Riemann tensor as $R_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}$. Due to the antisymmetry of the Riemann tensor, this would vanish if the spin tensor were symmetric.